# How can I get a PHP variable to AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, server-side-scripting

I don't think I am passing the variable the right way between my separate PHP and AJAX files.

I am debugging this by triggering the second condition `$status = 'info';` in my PHP file.

Currently, `status` is coming up as "undefined" for `alert(data.status);`

signup_process.php

```
if (condition){

   $status = 'success';

else {

    $status = 'info';

    }
```

AJAX

```
function send() {
var data = $('#signup_form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "signup_process.php",
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
        alert(data.status);
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                // everything went alright, submit
                $('#signup_form').submit();
            } else if (data.status == 'info')
            {
                console.log(data.status);
                $("label#email_error").show(); 
                return false; 
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

I know that the 2nd condition is being triggered because I put a header redirect there just for testing and it worked fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good to use **json** while return back data from php to ajax.

```
$return_data = array();
if (condition){
   $return_data['status'] = 'success';
} else {
    $return_data['status'] = 'info';
}

echo json_encode($return_data);
exit();
```

Now, if you are return back json data to ajax, then you need to **specify return data type into ajax** call as below

```
function send() {
var data = $('#signup_form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "signup_process.php",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function (data) {
        alert(data.status);
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                // everything went alright, submit
                $('#signup_form').submit();
            } else if (data.status == 'info')
            {
                console.log(data.status);
                $("label#email_error").show(); 
                return false; 
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

Comment: I added the datatype and the variable is still coming up as "undefined". I just tested to make sure the set "info" conditional was triggering and it is. In this case, shouldn't `(data.status)` be `(return_data.status)`? Thanks.

Comment: no. it should be data.status only. return_data.status this is wrong

Comment: `datatype: 'json'` should be `dataType: 'json'`as it's case sensitive

Comment: @spider, yes you are right. i missed it.. thanks.. edite my answer

Answer (score 3):

You should send a JSON object back from php:

```
$data = array();
if (condition){
   $data['status'] = 'success';
else {
   $data['status'] = 'info';
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

The [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) method converts the array to a JSON object so you can access each array key by name on the js side.

Comment: Okay, but I'm unsure why I need an array if it's only one value at a time per the conditional. Or is it sending as a key/value pair? I just tried this with all the code on the 2nd conditional's block `$data = array(); //send variables back to AJAX
    $data['status'] = 'info';
    echo json_encode($data);
    }` Should the AJAX portion work as I have written it?

Comment: you need to change datatype:'json' into ajax call to get json data in return

Comment: I've modified the answer to include the correct JSON `Content-Type `header, because jQuery Ajax guesses the response data type based on that, if you don't specify the `dataType` parameter in your ajax parameters (which you haven't specified).

Comment: @user1390395 As an alternative you can specify the `dataType: 'json'` parameter like @GBD pointed out but it must be camel case with a capital `T`. All lowercase won't work as the parameter name is case-sensitive

Comment: @spider, yes you are right. i missed camel case.. thanks.. edited my answer

Comment: @user1390395 - yes, JSON is a key-value pair system, which is why an array is used.... e.g. array('hello'=>'mum') is encoded to the JSON string {"hello":"mum"}. jQuery would then decode this automatically for you in to a javascript object that has the property '.hello' with a value of 'mum'