# Getting data with php in a javascript file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Echo PHP variable from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998457/echo-php-variable-from-javascript)
>   [How can I get a PHP variable to AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762609/how-can-i-get-a-php-variable-to-ajax)

I'm trying to get some data from my database with php, and put it in a javascript variable. what is the easiest way to do that using JQuery ?

Comment: Has the page already loaded or are you doing this before the first page load?

Comment: Is this a question or just a collection of jargon?

Comment: no, after the page load.

Comment: Either way it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This is easiest for me, where $var is your array in PHP, being set to the variable "a" in Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = <?php echo json_encode($var); ?>;

</script>
```

Comment: and $var is declared where ? should I include the php file ??

Comment: $var is your PHP array you wish to get into javascript. couldn't hurt to include php.